# How to create this photo effect with photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, style-identification, photography

I have seen an effect on some photos that I would like to reproduce. I don't know how to call it but I would describe it as low contrast and neutral (if that makes any sense) and I would like to create something similar in photoshop.
Here are some sample photos:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Images from http://georginaskinner.com/

And also this other effect, which looks more like an analog picture:
[image]
[image]
[image]
Images from rollingnorth.tumblr.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the before and after for the first one, based on what I did:

[image]

I decided the general look and feel was more "overexposed", so to do that:

1. In Photoshop, select Image > Adjustments > Exposure.
2. Adjust the "Offset" slider to +0.1
3. Lower the "Gamma Correction" slider to 2

Photoshop gives you a number of ways to do this, but this was the simplest. Not all photos will act the same, so play with the sliders until you're happy with the look of the result.

For the second filter, I created the following:

[image]

On this, I started playing the curves at first, and then the channel mixer, but ultimately found the following was easier to manage.

1. In Photoshop, select Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation.
2. Adjust the "Hue" slider to something matching your desired feel. In my case, it was 172.
3. I lowered the "Saturation" slider to 26, and then adjusted the lightness to +17, looking at your photos for comparison.
4. The final step is to select the adjustment layer, and lower the opacity. 40% looked about right to me.

It's important to note that these steps will vary wildly based on the original photos, but they're a good place to start. Play around with what looks good to you. I find that if you're having difficulty choosing between two effects, such as a higher or lower saturation, try exaggerating them both. For instance, if you're having trouble deciding between a saturation of 26 or 36, try compare 16 to 46, and see which one you like more. (Using 31 as the middle.)